# Are there zero bytes after a `char` in a struct?

Tags: c, binary-tree, preorder

I'm trying to make sure I understand what the hidden assumptions here are.

This code here gives correct results.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct branch
{
    char flag;      //value
    struct branch *l; //left child
    struct branch *r; //right child
};

struct branch c={'c',NULL,NULL};
struct branch e={'e',NULL,NULL};
struct branch f={'f',NULL,NULL};
struct branch b={'b',&c,NULL};
struct branch d={'d',&e,&f};
struct branch a={'a',&b,&d};

void preorder(struct branch* t)
{
    printf(&t->flag);    //Seems ugly and errorprone
    if(t->l) preorder(t->l);
    if(t->r) preorder(t->r);
}

int main()
{
    preorder(&a);
}
```

Output, as expected, is `abcdef`

Can someone confirm my suspicions, that this only works because two things:

1. struct members get aligned at n-byte boundaries (n != 1)(n = 4, it seems, when asking sizeof()-s)
2. bytes not used by the first member (which is a `char`) up to the n-byte boundary are zeroed.

I see no other explanation for printf working correctly otherwise, as it expects a zero-terminated char[].

Furthermore, is it wise to do things like that (outside of a single-target embedded code situation, where the optimisation may outweigh the readability and portability issues), ie. are these assumptions more-or-less universally true?

First week of intermittently messing with C, so I'm pretty green.

Comment: `printf(&t->flag);` indeed is ugly.(it relies on the character after the .flag field being nul; which is not guaranteed) `printf("%c", t->flag);` would propbably be the standard way.

Comment: My first knee-jerk reflex was that it's marginally faster (I ran both once, and the %c version finished in 4x longer). I tried again and it turns out the earlier result was spurious. There is nothing to win in doing it this way, I guess.

Comment: Out of curiosity: Where is this code from? I see no reason to not use `printf` correctly (as Wildplasser suggests), or to use `putchar`.

Comment: The code in this form doesn't exist anywhere but my PC. It's part of a homework assignment, where, while putting it down, I didn't yet have an understanding of what I was doing or what the & and * actually are, or indeed, what's the difference between an address and a pointer. So I was messing around, and a combination of "Can I pass a single char to printf" and wild guessing led to this working code. Then when I tried to understand why it worked, I realized that I can't be sure unless I know how the individual parts act.

It's not my first post though. My first post was yesterday, no answers.

Comment: @mafso - ooh, `putchar`. Shows my experience that I didn't know about that.

Comment: Use `offsetof()` to determine the possible padding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To verify your assumptions, you can inspect the code at runtime with a debugger or by using some printf.

For example, with:

```
  char *ptr=(char *)&t;
  printf("%02X %02X %02X %02X\n",ptr[0],ptr[1],ptr[2],ptr[3]);
```

Indeed the assumptions you identified are very often true, but you can't rely on them. I definitely would say that

```
  printf(&t->flag);
```

is plainly wrong because it relies on assumptions that are not guaranteed by the standard.tt

Comment: I can only verify on the architectures available to me, and if it's common, I'm likely to find them true. It's good to have an experienced opinion on such things sometimes. I thought there could be some opportunity for speed, but it seems it pretty much comes out the same.

Comment: @Remo.D so it is not "plainly wrong because it relies on assumptions that are not guaranteed by the standard" but it is not portable and is plainly wrong if one wants to write code standard-dependent. If he wrote all his life just for this particular environment then maybe it wouldn't be wrong at all?

Comment: @0d0a well, the only (barely) acceptable case is if this is only going to be compiled again with the same compiler version on the same OS (again same version) etc. If it will live in binary form once compiled and test I would not frown upon it :)

Answer (score 2):

You can prove 1 and 2 by yourself (i use x64, that's why all is 8bytes aligned in structures)

```
objdump ./main -s -j .data

Contents of section .data:
 601030 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ................
 601040 63000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  c...............
 601050 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ................
 601060 65000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  e...............
 601070 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ................
 601080 66000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  f...............
 601090 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ................
 6010a0 62000000 00000000 40106000 00000000  b.......@.`.....
 6010b0 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ................
 6010c0 64000000 00000000 60106000 00000000  d.......`.`.....
 6010d0 80106000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ..`.............
 6010e0 61000000 00000000 a0106000 00000000  a.........`.....
 6010f0 c0106000 00000000                    ..`.....
```

Comment: Thanks! I did not know about that! Also sorry, I'm marking Remo D.-s answer as accepted, as he also answered the second part. I'd upvote but it seems I have insufficient reputation for even that yet :)

Comment: @Jostikas now you have